# Alternative to gl_TexCoord.xy to get texture coordinate

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sfml

I always did my shaders in glsl 3 (with the *#version 330* line) but it's starting to be pretty old, so I recently tried to make a shader in glsl 4, and use it with the SFML library for rendering, instead of pure openGL.
For now, my goal is to do a basic shader for a 2d game, which takes the color of each pixel of a texture and modify them. I always did that with `gl_TexCoord[0].xy`, but it seems to be depreciated now, so I searched and I heard that I must use the *in* and *out* variables with a vertex shader, so I tried.
 
*Fragment shader*

```c
#version 400

in vec2 fragCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform sampler2D image;

void main(){

    // Get the color
    vec4 color = texture( image, fragCoord );

    /*
     * Do things with the color
     */

    // Return the color
    fragColor = color;
}
```

*Vertex shader*

```c
#version 400

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoord;

out vec2 fragCoord;

void main(){

    // Set the position of the pixel and vertex (I guess)
    fragCoord = textureCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
}
```

I also seen that we could add the projection, model, and view matrices, but I don't know how to do that with SFML (I don't even think we can), and I don't want to learn some complex things about openGL or SFML just to change some colors on a 2d game, so here is my question:

**Is there an easy way to just get the coordinates of the pixel we're working on? Maybe get rid of the vertex shader, or use it without using matrices?**

Answer (score -1):

Unless you really want to learn a lot of nasty OpenGl, writing your own shaders just for textures is a little overkill. SFML can handle textures and shaders for you behind the scenes ([here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php) is a good article on how to use them) so you don't need to worry about shaders at all. Also note that you can change the color of SFML sprites (which is, I believe, what you are trying to do), with `sprite.setColor(sf::color(*whatever*));`. Plus, there's no problem in using `version 330`. That's what I usually use, albeit with `in` and `out` stuff as well.

If you really want to use your own shaders for fancy effects, like pixellation, blurring, etc. I can't help you much since I've only ever worked with pure OpenGl, so I don't know how the vertex information is handled by SFML, but [this](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/tree/master/examples/shader) is some interesting example code you can check out, [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-shader.php) is a tutorial, and [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Shader.php) is a reference.

To more directly answer your question. `gl_FragCoord` is a built-in variable with GLSL that keeps track of the fragments position, but you have to set `gl_Position` in the vertex shader. You can't get rid of the vertex shader if you are doing anything OpenGl related. You'd have to do fancy matrix stuff ([this](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) is a wonderful library) and probably buffer stuff ([like this](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle)) to tell GLSL yourself where everything is.